# FlowLayoutPanel Focus() does not work

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `FlowLayoutPanel` in a `TabControl`. When the form is first shown, the `FlowLayoutPanel` can scroll with mouse wheel and its `ContainsFocus` property is `true`. When I go to another tab and return to first, the focus is not there even after calling `flowPanel.Focus()`. `ContainsFocus` property is `false` until I click on some control in the panel. How to set the focus to `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: It cannot itself gain the input focus, despite the apparent evidence.  Via an owned control gaining focus is correct.

Comment: OK, but I tried flowPanel.Controls[0].Focus() and the result was the same (index 0 was only for test - this has to focus 1st owned control). Also, why there is Focus() method if it is not working?

Comment: It is a container control, it doesn't like getting the focus.  Since it has no way to indicate that it has the focus and has no use for keyboard input.  One of its child controls needs to get the focus.  This does tend to cause trouble with the mouse wheel, your question isn't nearly detailed enough to give a specific recommendation or solution.

Comment: Here is example. I can post Form1.Designer.cs file but it is too long and simple. For that reason I will explain it:

Comment: Set the focus on the first element of the control collection in the FlowLayoutPanel, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version Visual Studio you are using, but on the tabControl, I added the following...

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("\t");
}
```

This way, as soon as the tabbed-page is changed, it forces a "tab" key which forces to the first field within the page.  You should be able to run with that in case you need additional focus, such as: if on page 1 go to this field, if page 2, go to another field...

Comment: This works but what is different between sending tab (skip to next control) and directly calling Focus() method?

Comment: @i486, honestly, sometimes I just don't know, but do know of alternatives.  Just something I remembered doing way back in a winforms app myself.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when `form loads` or when changing the `tab`, all `mouse wheel` messages are processed by the `form`. So when that happens send the message to `flowLayoutPanel1` also:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x020A) //WM_MOUSEWHEEL
    {
        if(tabControl1 .SelectedIndex == 0) //0 index where flowLayoutPanel1 is
        {
             //send the message to flowLayoutPanel1
             SendMessage(flowLayoutPanel1.Handle, (UInt32)m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```